# Is Rails Collection_Select onchange still supported?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a text field that is visible only when the user selects "Other" from a dropdown menu.

I've done this before with some jQuery and rails "select" but I haven't been able to get it working for "collection_select".

People say that onChange should work but so far I have had no luck.

Collection Select:

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:professor, Professor.order(:fullname), :id, :fullname,
     include_blank: false, :prompt => "Other", :onchange => "review_professor();")%>
     <%= f.text_field :professor, class: "class-reveal", style: "display: none;"%>
```

Javascript:

```
    review_professor = function() {
     if(this.value == "Other") {
       $('.class-reveal').show();
       $('.class-reveal').val('');
     }else{
       $('.class-reaveal').hide();
       $('.class-reveal').val(this.value);
     }
   });
```

Any ideas of why this is not working or another way I can do this?   Is collection_select still supported?

Answer (score 2):

It still works for collection_select, it just needs to go in the [html_options hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), like so:

```
{include_blank: false, prompt: "Other"}, {onchange: "review_professor();"}
```